# Changing Readonly attribute of Textbox within a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

On my aspx page i have a repeater with 5 textboxes with 1 imagebutton to edit the row
these textboxes are readonly, to edit them I need them to not be readOnly..

In my behind code i am using :

```
protected void EditRecipeInfo(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton ib = sender as ImageButton;

    TextBox titleTXT = (TextBox)ib.FindControl("titleRepeat");
    TextBox qtyTXT = (TextBox)ib.FindControl("qtyRepeat");
    TextBox uomTXT = (TextBox)ib.FindControl("uomRepeat");
    TextBox prepTXT = (TextBox)ib.FindControl("prepRepeat");
    TextBox orTXT = (TextBox)ib.FindControl("orRepeat");

    titleTXT.ReadOnly = false;
    qtyTXT.ReadOnly = false;
    uomTXT.ReadOnly = false;
    prepTXT.ReadOnly = false;
    orTXT.ReadOnly = false;
    ////
}
```

But when I fire this event the break points show me that the property is being set to false, but when I click to delete any value in the textbox it still acts like a readonly

**UPDATE:**

```xml
  <asp:Repeater ID="ingredRepeater" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table style="width: 100%">
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th><h2>Title</h2></th>
                            <th><h2>Qty.</h2></th>
                            <th><h2>UoM</h2></th>
                            <th><h2>Prep.</h2></th>
                            <th><h2>Alternate</h2></th>
                        </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton Style="height: 25px; width: 25px;" ImageUrl="/img/edit.png" Visible="true"
                                ID="editRecipeInfo" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnCommand="EditRecipeInfo" CommandName='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.DetailID") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="/img/RedX.png" ID="button2" runat="server" Height="20"
                                Width="20" CommandName='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.DetailID") %>'
                                OnCommand="deleteRecipeView" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox AutoPostBack="true" ReadOnly="true" ID="titleRepeat" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Name") %>'
                                size="45" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox  AutoPostBack="true" ReadOnly='true' ID="qtyRepeat" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Quantity") %>'
                                size="10" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox AutoPostBack="true"  ReadOnly='true' ID="uomRepeat" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.UnitsOfMeasure") %>'
                                size="10" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox AutoPostBack="true"  ReadOnly='true' ID="prepRepeat" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Prep") %>'
                                size="10" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox AutoPostBack="true"  ReadOnly='true' ID="orRepeat" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.AlternativeIngredients") %>'
                                size="20" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Could you please post your markup?

Comment: clicked the button from the image and the event is triggered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're not re-binding the repeater after you set the ReadOnly property to true.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Tariqulazam , the markup would help.

Assuming your code comes from an ItemCommand event handler, I am quite surprised to see the FindControl applied to the ImageButton.

I guess your code should be something like this :

```
void rpAcces_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
  {
  //...
  ImageButton ib = sender as ImageButton;

  TextBox titleTXT = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("titleRepeat");
  TextBox qtyTXT = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("qtyRepeat");
  TextBox uomTXT = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("uomRepeat");
  TextBox prepTXT = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("prepRepeat");
  TextBox orTXT = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("orRepeat");

  titleTXT.ReadOnly = false;
  qtyTXT.ReadOnly = false;
  uomTXT.ReadOnly = false;
  prepTXT.ReadOnly = false;
  orTXT.ReadOnly = false;
  //...
 }
```

Also, be aware that you can not rebind your repeater later in the page life-cycle without losing these changes. 
And watch out for any *Enabled* attribute set on your TextBoxes

Once again, difficult to answer without the whole code.

Comment: Fixed.  my Page_load, wasnt configured right and i was rebinding the repeater and it was overriding it.